# Setting Javascript from applying to entire document to div only

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I found a codepen which allowed me to have confettis falling with javascript. The javascript code applies to the entire body, hence confettis are falling all over the entire document. Instead, I want the confettis effect to only apply to my div (confettis-section). I am still a beginner to the language and hence not sure how to modify it to the way I want. Would appreciate any help thanks.

```
<div class="confettis-section">
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/Pillowfication/pen/PNEJbY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your updated codepen link: https://codepen.io/bhuwanb9/pen/KZWjVg

```js
'use strict';

// If set to true, the user must press
// UP UP DOWN ODWN LEFT RIGHT LEFT RIGHT A B
// to trigger the confetti with a random color theme.
// Otherwise the confetti constantly falls.
var onlyOnKonami = false;

$(function() {
  // Globals
  var $window = $('#area'),
    random = Math.random,
    cos = Math.cos,
    sin = Math.sin,
    PI = Math.PI,
    PI2 = PI * 2,
    timer = undefined,
    frame = undefined,
    confetti = [];

  // Settings
  var konami = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65],
    pointer = 0;

  var particles = 150,
    spread = 40,
    sizeMin = 3,
    sizeMax = 12 - sizeMin,
    eccentricity = 10,
    deviation = 100,
    dxThetaMin = -.1,
    dxThetaMax = -dxThetaMin - dxThetaMin,
    dyMin = .13,
    dyMax = .18,
    dThetaMin = .4,
    dThetaMax = .7 - dThetaMin;

  var colorThemes = [
    function() {
      return color(200 * random() | 0, 200 * random() | 0, 200 * random() | 0);
    },
    function() {
      var black = 200 * random() | 0;
      return color(200, black, black);
    },
    function() {
      var black = 200 * random() | 0;
      return color(black, 200, black);
    },
    function() {
      var black = 200 * random() | 0;
      return color(black, black, 200);
    },
    function() {
      return color(200, 100, 200 * random() | 0);
    },
    function() {
      return color(200 * random() | 0, 200, 200);
    },
    function() {
      var black = 256 * random() | 0;
      return color(black, black, black);
    },
    function() {
      return colorThemes[random() < .5 ? 1 : 2]();
    },
    function() {
      return colorThemes[random() < .5 ? 3 : 5]();
    },
    function() {
      return colorThemes[random() < .5 ? 2 : 4]();
    }
  ];

  function color(r, g, b) {
    return 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
  }

  // Cosine interpolation
  function interpolation(a, b, t) {
    return (1 - cos(PI * t)) / 2 * (b - a) + a;
  }

  // Create a 1D Maximal Poisson Disc over [0, 1]
  var radius = 1 / eccentricity,
    radius2 = radius + radius;

  function createPoisson() {
    // domain is the set of points which are still available to pick from
    // D = union{ [d_i, d_i+1] | i is even }
    var domain = [radius, 1 - radius],
      measure = 1 - radius2,
      spline = [0, 1];
    while (measure) {
      var dart = measure * random(),
        i, l, interval, a, b, c, d;

      // Find where dart lies
      for (i = 0, l = domain.length, measure = 0; i < l; i += 2) {
        a = domain[i], b = domain[i + 1], interval = b - a;
        if (dart < measure + interval) {
          spline.push(dart += a - measure);
          break;
        }
        measure += interval;
      }
      c = dart - radius, d = dart + radius;

      // Update the domain
      for (i = domain.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 2) {
        l = i - 1, a = domain[l], b = domain[i];
        // c---d          c---d  Do nothing
        //   c-----d  c-----d    Move interior
        //   c--------------d    Delete interval
        //         c--d          Split interval
        //       a------b
        if (a >= c && a < d)
          if (b > d) domain[l] = d; // Move interior (Left case)
          else domain.splice(l, 2); // Delete interval
        else if (a < c && b > c)
          if (b <= d) domain[i] = c; // Move interior (Right case)
          else domain.splice(i, 0, c, d); // Split interval
      }

      // Re-measure the domain
      for (i = 0, l = domain.length, measure = 0; i < l; i += 2)
        measure += domain[i + 1] - domain[i];
    }

    return spline.sort();
  }

  // Create the overarching container
  var areaTop = document.getElementById("area").offsetTop + 'px',
    areaLeft = document.getElementById("area").offsetLeft + 'px',
    areaWidth = document.getElementById("area").offsetWidth + 'px',
    areaHeight = document.getElementById("area").offsetHeight + 'px';
  console.log(areaTop, areaLeft, areaWidth, areaHeight)
  var container = document.createElement('div');
  container.style.position = 'fixed';
  container.style.top = areaTop;
  container.style.left = areaLeft;
  container.style.width = areaWidth;
  container.style.height = areaHeight;
  container.style.overflow = 'visible';
  container.style.zIndex = '9999';

  // Confetto constructor
  function Confetto(theme) {
    this.frame = 0;
    this.outer = document.createElement('div');
    this.inner = document.createElement('div');
    this.outer.appendChild(this.inner);

    var outerStyle = this.outer.style,
      innerStyle = this.inner.style;
    outerStyle.position = 'absolute';
    outerStyle.width = (sizeMin + sizeMax * random()) + 'px';
    outerStyle.height = (sizeMin + sizeMax * random()) + 'px';
    innerStyle.width = '100%';
    innerStyle.height = '100%';
    innerStyle.backgroundColor = theme();

    outerStyle.perspective = '50px';
    outerStyle.transform = 'rotate(' + (360 * random()) + 'deg)';
    this.axis = 'rotate3D(' +
      cos(360 * random()) + ',' +
      cos(360 * random()) + ',0,';
    this.theta = 360 * random();
    this.dTheta = dThetaMin + dThetaMax * random();
    innerStyle.transform = this.axis + this.theta + 'deg)';

    this.x = $window.width() * random();
    this.y = -deviation;
    this.dx = sin(dxThetaMin + dxThetaMax * random());
    this.dy = dyMin + dyMax * random();
    outerStyle.left = this.x + 'px';
    outerStyle.top = this.y + 'px';

    // Create the periodic spline
    this.splineX = createPoisson();
    this.splineY = [];
    for (var i = 1, l = this.splineX.length - 1; i < l; ++i)
      this.splineY[i] = deviation * random();
    this.splineY[0] = this.splineY[l] = deviation * random();

    this.update = function(height, delta) {
      this.frame += delta;
      this.x += this.dx * delta;
      this.y += this.dy * delta;
      this.theta += this.dTheta * delta;

      // Compute spline and convert to polar
      var phi = this.frame % 7777 / 7777,
        i = 0,
        j = 1;
      while (phi >= this.splineX[j]) i = j++;
      var rho = interpolation(
        this.splineY[i],
        this.splineY[j],
        (phi - this.splineX[i]) / (this.splineX[j] - this.splineX[i])
      );
      phi *= PI2;

      outerStyle.left = this.x + rho * cos(phi) + 'px';
      outerStyle.top = this.y + rho * sin(phi) + 'px';
      innerStyle.transform = this.axis + this.theta + 'deg)';
      return this.y > height + deviation;
    };
  }

  function poof() {
    if (!frame) {
      // Append the container
      document.body.appendChild(container);

      // Add confetti
      var theme = colorThemes[onlyOnKonami ? colorThemes.length * random() | 0 : 0],
        count = 0;
      (function addConfetto() {
        if (onlyOnKonami && ++count > particles)
          return timer = undefined;

        var confetto = new Confetto(theme);
        confetti.push(confetto);
        container.appendChild(confetto.outer);
        timer = setTimeout(addConfetto, spread * random());
      })(0);

      // Start the loop
      var prev = undefined;
      requestAnimationFrame(function loop(timestamp) {
        var delta = prev ? timestamp - prev : 0;
        prev = timestamp;
        var height = $window.height();

        for (var i = confetti.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
          if (confetti[i].update(height, delta)) {
            container.removeChild(confetti[i].outer);
            confetti.splice(i, 1);
          }
        }

        if (timer || confetti.length)
          return frame = requestAnimationFrame(loop);

        // Cleanup
        document.body.removeChild(container);
        frame = undefined;
      });
    }
  }

  $window.keydown(function(event) {
    pointer = konami[pointer] === event.which ?
      pointer + 1 :
      +(event.which === konami[0]);
    if (pointer === konami.length) {
      pointer = 0;
      poof();
    }
  });

  if (!onlyOnKonami) poof();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #111;
}

#area {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="area"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I tried it but it does not seem to be working as intended. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzpGeZ

Comment: I am trying to make the confetti effect appear only on the 2nd column (right)

Comment: @Jason Did some alignment changes in your codepen. See updated link above

Answer (score 0):

I changed the HTML and JS

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col m6"style="width:50%; height: 30vh; border: 1px solid black">
    <h4>Hi</h4>
    <h4>Hi</h4>
    <h4>Hi</h4>
</div>
  <div class="col m6" id="area">
    <h4>Hi</h4>
    <h4>Hi</h4>
    <h4>Hi</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

I changed lines 115 onwards to:

```
var container = document.getElementById('area');
  container.style.position = 'fixed';
  container.style.top      = '0';
  container.style.left     = '50vw'; //<-- start from half the screen width
  container.style.width    = '50%';//<-- width of container itself is 50% of screen
  container.style.height   = '30vh';//<--height of area is 30/100 of screen height
  container.style.overflow = 'visible';
  container.style.zIndex   = '9999';
  container.style.border = '1px solid black';//<--setting border here
```

I removed the border css for the col class and added it in the HTML and JS for the two different columns

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzpGeZ

Comment: changed my answer to what you were looking for